Find max of $(3x^2-2xy+3y^2)(3y^2-2yz+3z^2)(3z^2-2xz+3x^2)$
If $x, y, z \ge 0$ and $x+y+z=2$, find max

$P = (3x^2-2xy+3y^2)(3y^2-2yz+3z^2)(3z^2-2zx+3x^2)$

What i tried: Let $a = x+\frac{z}{2}, b=y+\frac{z}{2} => a+b=2$ WLOG $z≤x,y$, then i prove
$$3x^2-2xz+3z^2 \le 3(x-\frac{z}{2})^2$$
$$<=> 5xz - \frac{9}{4}z^2 \ge 0$$
Which is true because $z\le x$ so $5xz \ge 5z^2$, similary with
$$3y^2-2xz+3z^2 \le 3(y-\frac{z}{2})^2$$
so $P \le 9a^2b^2(3x^2-2xy+3y^2) \le \frac{9}{16}(a+b)^4(3x^2-2xy+3y^2)=9(3x^2-2xy+3y^2)$
But i couldn't proceed much with $3x^2-2xy+3y^2$
The equality case is $x=y=1, z=0$. Could someone provide hints?

Is there any statement stating that x,y,z>0?

Take $z=0$, $x = -n$, $y=n+2$ and you have :
$$P = 9n^2(n+2)^2(10n^2+16n+12).$$
So I suspect you have condition like $x,y,z\geq 0.$

Yes, $x,y,z \ge 0$, thanks

Proceeding along OP's lines.
WLOG, assume that $x, y \ge z$.
Let $a = x + z/2, b = y + z/2$.
Using OP's result and AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 P &\le 9a^2b^2(3x^2 - 2xy + 3y^2)\\
 &= \frac{9}{16}(4ab)(4ab)(3x^2 - 2xy + 3y^2)\\
 &\le \frac{9}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{27}(4ab + 4ab + 3x^2 - 2xy + 3y^2)^3\\
 &= \frac{1}{48}(3x^2 + 3y^2 + 2z^2 + 6xy + 4yz + 4zx)^3\\
 &\le \frac{1}{48}(3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2 + 6xy + 6yz + 6zx)^3\\
 &= \frac{1}{48}\Big(3(x + y + z)^2\Big)^3\\
 &= 36.
\end{align*}
Also, when $x = y = 1, z = 0$, we have $P = 36$.
Thus, the maximum of $P$ is $36$.
